# qooxdoo: DOM to qx.html.Element tree

Tags: svg, qooxdoo

Given already parsed browser DOM, are there any mechanisms in qooxdoo that can facilitate conversion of DOM into a tree of qx.html.Element instances? Specifically, I'm planning to develop an SVG parser for [qooxdoo SVG](http://qooxdoo.org/contrib/project/svg). If there a way other than traversing the DOM tree and wrapping elements manually?

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately not. The qooxdoo widgets need to create their own HTML elements. This is how the widgets are currently written.

Comment: Martin, in fact I don't need to restore a tree of qooxdoo widgets from DOM. Fortunately, my problem can be narrowed down to restoring a tree of qx.html.Element instances from DOM. For that, I hope qx.html.Element#useElement can be used.